# part of field is a date...sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

In a datatable there is a field which is name and in about 70% of the time, also the birthday of the person included.
This birthday I would need to extract to a new field, however the below inserted script throws a

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character  string" error message

(I understand why).
I was trying with "case when" type of code, but eventually never did work out.

```
  select [NAM_FULL_NAME_INR]
      ,datepart(month, CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING([NAM_FULL_NAME_INR], patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', [NAM_FULL_NAME_INR]), 50))) AS MONTHARCHIVED
,datepart(YEAR, CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING([NAM_FULL_NAME_INR], patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', [NAM_FULL_NAME_INR]), 50))) AS YEAR_ARCHIVED
FROM tablename
```

can please somebody help with this?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the table and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query uses product specific functions.)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would really hep.

Comment: I've added the Sql-Server tag based on syntax and error message.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: sample of the table: NAM_FULL_NAME_INR
Tomas Schmitt 08.05.1952
IMMO Gmbh
Klaudia Re 01.01.1999
Martin Ka 27.03.1976
Barbara Ler 11.11.1969
Wageeh Ar 26.10.1965
Maeda Ro Ltd.
Daisue Co Ltd.
Hans Ganly
Adir Batvic 23.08.1977
Omir Ner 27.09.1977
Peter Kais 22.05.1964
Grigore Soln 28.03.1965
Adelheid Fux
Josefa Zainger
Sonja Dolln

Comment: as you can see in sample of the table above, some cases the person has the name, and the birthday together in the same field , and sometimes it is only the name

Comment: the desire would be a field where only the birthday would show up (month) and one the year of the birthday. In case the birthday is not there, than it is returning empty field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the birthdays always have the same format, you can use the pattern features of `LIKE` in SQL Server to check, if there is a birthday at the end. Use `[0-9]` to match any single character form `0` to `9`. The '%' matches any character any times.

So the `LIKE` expression to check for the birthday is:

```
%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Pack that in `CASE ... END`s, to extract and possibly convert the substrings, if a birthday is appended.

Since the birthday pattern has a fixed length, that can be achieved by using `substring()`, `len()` and some arithmetic operations.

`convert()` then converts the string to a `date` using the German date style (`104` for four digit years).

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN nam_full_name_inr LIKE '%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN
           substring(nam_full_name_inr, 1, len(nam_full_name_inr) - 11)
         ELSE
           nam_full_name_inr
       END name,
       CASE
         WHEN nam_full_name_inr LIKE '%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN
           convert(date, substring(nam_full_name_inr, len(nam_full_name_inr) - 9, 10), 104)
       END birthday
       FROM elbat;
```